# How does LinearModelFit handle cases where the design matrix rank is lower than the model terms?

Tags: fitting

So, I understand what this error means:

```
LinearModelFit::rank: The rank of the design matrix 6 is less than the number of terms 8 in the model. The model and results based upon it may contain significant numerical error. >>
```

What I don't understand is what Mathematica does do in these cases, because it happily returns a model with 8 (nonzero) best fit coefficients. The R^2 is understandably 1.0, but shouldn't there be infinite solutions?

To be clear, I know how to fix the problem; what I'm trying to understand is the machinery under the hood that produces a repeatable result when my instinct tells me there should be infinite solutions. Does it simply pick one at random?

Thanks!

==========================================

At the request of @J. M.'s technical difficulties, I have added a simple example.

```
x = Range[0, 3];
y = x^5 - 5 x^4 + 3 x^2 + 2 x + 1;

LinearModelFit[Transpose[{x, y}], {t^5, t^4, t^3, t^2, t, 1}, {t}]
```

Which results in the error:

```
LinearModelFit::rank: The rank of the design matrix 4 is less than the number of terms 6 in the model. The model and results based upon it may contain significant numerical error.
```

But does give the following linear model:

```
1. + 10.7236 t - 6.95173 t^2 - 2.35244 t^3 - 0.412476 t^4 -  0.00690827 t^5
```

It is easy to see why this error occurs, we have only got 4 data points but are trying to fit a degree 5 polynomial to the data (which has 6 parameters that need to be estimated), and there are infinitely many degree 5 polynomials that perfectly fit the 4 data points.

What I would like to know, and so did @cjdrover when the question was first asked is; why/how does Mathematica pick the linear model that it does in cases such as this one?

Of course, the exact same happens if instead of having too few data points, there is linear dependence within the set of points that mean the design matrix in it's reduced state without points with linear dependence, there are too few points. An example of this would be:

```
x = {0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3};
y = x^5 - 5 x^4 + 3 x^2 + 2 x + 1;

LinearModelFit[Transpose[{x, y}], {t^5, t^4, t^3, t^2, t, 1}, {t}]
```

Which will give both the exact same error message as before as well as the exact same result as before.

Comment: @wilsnunn, since you're offering the bounty: could you perhaps provide a simple example that triggers the error message? But one should remember that the procedure is called **least** squares: that is, the coefficients returned are precisely the solution $\mathbf c$ that minimizes $\|\mathbf A\mathbf c-\mathbf b\|_2$, where $\mathbf A$ and $\mathbf b$ are respectively the design matrix and response vector. Getting the error usually means you have basis functions that are dependent on each other.